# Jmeter setup specific parameters on different host

Tags: jmeter

My test plan use a parameter as `startIndex`.

In local case:
"thread pool 1" -> "Java Request" -> "Send Parameters With the Request" -> Add a parameter named `startIndex`, 
and Create a config element - "User Defined variables", and  give a parameter `startIndex`.

But how to  give different `startIndex` parameters to each server, 
for example:

> serverA:"startIndex"=100, serverB:"startIndex"=200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. On each JMeter slave machine locate *user.properties* file under /bin folder of your JMeter installation
2. Add the following lines to this file:

   - on server 1: `startIndex=100`
   - on server 2: `startIndex=200`
3. Refer `startIndex` property value via [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) as `${__P(startIndex,)}` where required

Make sure you restart JMeter after *user.properties* file modification.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for extended information on JMeter properties and ways of working with them

Answer (score 0):

It is not a best practice to have create two variables having same names. If this situation is unavoidable then do not use 'user defined variables. Instead you can create the second variable under specific sampler, by using beanshell (vars.put) to create second variable. Not a tested technique but you can try.